# Errors with array values in terrain representation

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, math

I'm looking to make a fence made with 1's and 0's to represent terrain. 1 will be the fences, and 0 will be the empty spaces. Here is my code:

```
package assignment_2;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Fencing {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        boolean b = true;
        int i;
        int j;
        final int[][] map = { { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 2, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 3, 0 }, { 1, 4, 0, 0 } };
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                    b = false;

                    if (b == false) {
                        System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format");
                        b = true;
                        while (i < 4 && j < 4) {
                            System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
                            i++;
                            j++;

                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The map is valid");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now this code scrolls through the array values, and if there are values that are not 1's or 0's then it reports them back to the user. If there are no errors it should report back "The map is valid". I have 2 problems, the first is that when the array is correct and has no errors (Is made of only 1's and 0's) It doesn't display anything, where it should be displaying "The map has the correct format". The second problem is the more important one, where there seems to be something wrong with the bottom line of the array. It skips over the incorrect values like the 4 and just reports the ending line, which is a 0 at location 3,3. This is a correct value so I'm not sure what's up with that. Other lines don't have this problem, they report back the correct errors like the 3 and the 2. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger?

Comment: These two lines of code are pointless, aren't they: `b = false; if (b == false) {`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem: You set `b` to `false`, and in the next line you ask `if( b == false)`. So thats obviously `true` and the else block is never called.

Doing `if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0){` and at the same time using the boolean `b` is redundant.

For the second problem: Once you find a wrong number you go diagonal trough your map (by increasing `i` and `j` at the same time) and print every number until you reach either the right or the bottom end of your map. I don't think that is what you wanted to archive. Since I don't know what you wanted to print out, I can't tell you how to solve this one.

Edit: If you nly wanted to print the one incorrect Number, you don't need a while loop inside the double for loops, just print the incorrect value and let the double for loops continue theire work

Edit 2: A possible solution to your problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
            b = false;
            System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
        }
    }
}

if(b){
    System.out.println("The map is valid");
}else{
    System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format");
}
```

The only downside to this solution is, that it prints the error message after printing the incorrect values.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm trying to do is get it to look through all the numbers and report back all the ones that were incorrect. I checked and you were right that it is going diagonally after the first error, do you know what I would change with i++ and j++?

Comment: In case you haven't solved your problem yet, I will add a possible solution to your problem.